# How can I check a radio button before submitting the form with a button?

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, radio-button

I have a form with a table and each row of that table is a different offer. So, I also have some buttons in each row to download the documentation of the offer or delete the offer. That buttons submit the form and they go to another php file that does the desired action.

My problem is that the radio button of the desired row has to be checked before I submit the form. Is there any way with javascript that when you click one of those two button, first it selects automatically the radio button of that row and then submits the form?

```
<form class="filterSelection" action="../php/editOffer/getInfo.php" method="POST">
    <table class="accountsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selected</th>
                <th>Project ID</th>
                <th>Revision</th>
                <th>Project Description</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Documentation</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="selectedOffer" id="selectedOffer" required="" value="1-1"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>2020-02-10</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="download" name="action" value="Download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="submit" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br>
    <button name="action" class="nextButton" type="submit" value="Next"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-2x"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Sure there is. What have you tried?

Comment: Would it not make more sense just to have the radio buttons on each row, and then a single download/delete button at the bottom, which acts on the item selected in the radio button? Either that, or get rid of the radio button entirely and have separate forms in row with a hidden field which records the selection. Right now you seem to be jumbling two different UI patterns together into one.

Comment: @ADyson Because I need to submit the value of the radio button. Sorry, but I´m new to this, can I make that with hidden field? And if that´s possible, how does it work?

Comment: Sorry, not sure which comments you're replying to. I added several, but then I re-thought all those comments and deleted them, and just added a much simpler one. As I've indicated in my one remaining comment above, there are two ways you would normally approach this design. One of them keeps your radio options but reduces the number of buttons. The other keeps the buttons and replaces the radio options with hidden fields.

Comment: @ADyson First of all, thanks for all your help. I have never used hidden fields and I don´t know how they work. How can I pass the value of them when I click in one button? Sorry if t´s a silly question

Comment: A hidden field looks something like `<input type="hidden" name="selectedOffer" value="1-1"/>`. When the form is submitted, the value in the hidden field would be sent to the server as part of the form data, just like input from textboxes, radio buttons etc. You can easily google examples of them. So in your case if you had a separate `<form>` for each offer, containing just the hidden field and the two Download and Delete buttons, then if the user clicked Download or Delete it would submit the form containing the offer value from the hidden field within that form.

Comment: @d1649356 That's great. I think you should add your finished version as an Answer below (especially as all of the attempts below have either missed the point, got bugs in them, or require pointless extra code libraries to be added to your page - or some combination of those issues!). You're allowed and encouraged to answer your own question, which then gives others the chance to upvote your answer if they find it useful for a similar problem (and your question also shows more in search results if there's a good accepted answer).

Comment: @ADyson Sorry, I thought that it worked well but that is not the case. If I had more than one row, I have to put more than one hidden inputs and when I click one button it always takes the last hidden input value

Comment: @d1649356 Of course I can't see what you've done exactly, but from what you've described I would guess that maybe you forgot about the bit where I said that for this approach there must be a separate `<form></form>` tag for each row? Therefore each individual form would only ever include one hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the closest tr to find the specific radio button. Then set the *checked* attribute using `setAttribute()`.

You can try the following way:

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[type=submit');
buttons.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(el, e){
    this.closest('tr').querySelector('[type=radio]').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    alert(this.closest('tr').querySelector('[type=radio]').getAttribute('checked'));
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form class = "filterSelection" action = "../php/editOffer/getInfo.php" method = "POST">
  <table class = "accountsTable">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Selected</th>
              <th>Project ID</th>
              <th>Revision</th>
              <th>Project Description</th>
              <th>Customer</th>
              <th>Date</th>
              <th>Creator</th>
              <th>Documentation</th>
              <th>Delete</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="selectedOffer" id="selectedOffer" value="1-1">
            </td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Test</td>
             <td>Info</td>
             <td>2020-02-10</td>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="download" name="action" value="Download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" name="selectedOffer" id="selectedOffer" value="1-1">
            </td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Test</td>
             <td>Info</td>
             <td>2020-02-10</td>
             <td>Name</td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="download" name="action" value="Download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </td>
             <td><button type="submit" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table><br>
  <button name="action" class="nextButton" type="submit" value="Next"><i class="fa fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-2x"></i>    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: You've missed the point that it should not ask the user to select an option. It should **automatically** select the radio button nearest to the button which was clicked. Read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some small changes in you form like below :

```
<form class="filterSelection" id="filter-form" action="../php/editOffer/getInfo.php" method="POST">
    <table class="accountsTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selected</th>
                <th>Project ID</th>
                <th>Revision</th>
                <th>Project Description</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Creator</th>
                <th>Documentation</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="selectedOffer" id="selectedOffer-1" value="1-1"></td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Test</td>
                <td>Info</td>
                <td>2020-02-10</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><button type="button" name="action" data-row="1" onclick="btnAction(this)" value="Download"><i
                            class="fa fa-download" data-row="1" aria-hidden="true"></i> Download</button>
                </td>
                <td><button type="button" name="action" onclick="btnAction(this)" value="Delete">
                        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table><br>
    <button name="submit" class="nextButton" type="button" value="Next"><i
            class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right fa-2x"></i> Next</button>
</form>
```

Now here is the javascript code to check some validation :

```
<script>
    function btnAction(btn) {
        var row = btn.dataset.row;
        var radio = document.getElementById("selectedOffer-"+row);
        radio.checked = true;
        document.getElementById("filter-form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Hope this will work for you solution

Comment: I have edit the answer will may be this will work for the question

Comment: Thanks but you've still missed the point that it should not ask the user to select an option. It should **automatically** select the radio button nearest to the button which was clicked. Read the question more carefully. Also please remove all references to jQuery from your text. And lastly the code and text near the end seem to be in the wrong order.

Comment: Yes, the function `btnAction(btn)` you can see in code that will automactically select the nearest radio and second function `checkIsSelected()` will scan all radio with `selectedOffer` name and check whether anyone of them are selected or not

Comment: But then in that case there is no purpose to checkIsSelected(), surely? You don't have to check anything or prompt the user, if the code is just going to select it anyway. That's why I was confused. I don't see why you need the checkIsSelected function at all.

Comment: If you can see there is next button at to bottom so if user click directly on next button without selecting radio, form should not be submited or else If you want to select all radio on next button then you can simple add `element.checked=true` in forEach and remove the all conditions from the function `checkIsSelected()`

Comment: But OP did not put any such requirements on the "next" button. The radio button value is only required if one of the "download" or "delete" buttons is pressed.

Comment: @ADyson I have edit the answer, I was miss undertstood by the first line **(My problem is that the radio button of the desired row has to be checked before I submit the form.)** of second paragraph in your question so I gave solution in that way.

Comment: It's not **my** question :-). yes that is a bit ambiguous, but I suspect the OP has simply forgotten to take that button into account.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved adding a hidden input and deleting the radio buttons. I have also change the structure of the forms. Now, this is my code that works:

```
<table class = "accountsTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Project ID</th>
                    <th>Revision</th>
                    <th>Project Description</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Creator</th>
                    <th>Download</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                    <form class="filterSelection" action="../php/editOffer/getInfo.php" method="POST">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>Test</td>
                        <td>Info</td>
                        <td>2020-02-10</td>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="download" name="action" value="Download"><i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            </td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" 
                                    onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')">
                                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
                        <td><button name="action" class="edit" type="submit" value="Next"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="selectedOffer" value="1-1"/>
                    </form>
                </tr>
                                        <tr>
                    <form class="filterSelection" action="../php/editOffer/getInfo.php" method="POST">
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>Demo</td>
                        <td>Info1</td>
                        <td>2020-02-13</td>
                        <td>Name1</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><button type="submit" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" 
                                    onclick="return confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')">
                                <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
                        <td><button name="action" class="edit" type="submit" value="Next"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></button></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="selectedOffer" value="1-2"/>
                    </form>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

## add on click event to the button

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="delete" name="action" value="Delete" onclick="someAction(this);">
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
</td>
```

## Jquery Code

Add Jquery library to the page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Use below script

```
function someAction(ds) {

   if(!$(ds).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){         

     $(ds).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked',true);
     if(confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')){
          $(ds).parents('form').submit();
     }
  }               
}
```

Comment: That´s not what I want. I want that when you click the button, the radio button be selected automatically

Comment: if(!$(ds).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')){
              $(ds).closest('tr').find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked',true);
              if(confirm('Do you want to delete the selected offer? This action can´t be undone')){
                    $(ds).parents('form').submit();
                }
            }

Comment: use this script to automatically check the radio button if not checked and submit the form

Comment: why does everyone keep recommending jQuery when OP is not using it and hasn't asked for it. This is the 3rd (including one deleted) answer to do so. There's nothing you can do in jQuery that can't be done using native JavaScript. There's no need to add the overhead of jQuery to the site just for one tiny feature. Anyway if you want to update your answer, add the updated code to the answer itself (using your answer's "edit" button), not into the comments.